# Matching many pattern in file listing command ls?

Tags: command-line

I have many files in my directory. I'd like to listing, copying or moving file containing 'abc' AND 'xyz' in their name. How do I do this pattern matching with AND?

The normal command: `ls *abc* *xyz*` only work with OR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this way.

```
ls *abc*xyz* *xyz*abc*
```

Using in `mv` or `cp`, you just need specify the target directory with `-t` option since you are looking the files with wildcards and can be more than a file to copy/move:

```
cp -t /path/to/dest *abc*xyz* *xyz*abc*
```

Or use `find` like:

```
find \( -name '*abc*' -a -name '*xyz*' \)
```

which is same as `find -name '*abc*' -name '*xyz*'` as documented in [**`man find`**](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html):

> **expr1 expr2**
>          Two expressions in a row are taken to be joined with an implied "and"; *expr2* is not evaluated if *expr1* is false.
>
> **expr1** -a **expr2**
>          Same as *expr1 expr2*.
>
> **expr1** -and **expr2**
>          Same as *expr1 expr2*, but not POSIX compliant.

You can add `-exec ...` to the command above to do whatever you want to do on the files found.

```
find \( -name '*abc*' -a -name '*xyz*' \) -exec do-stuffs {} +
```